# How to sort using ng-repeat with a key|value pair

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm attempting to list out some messaging threads for my application in the order of the last message (So that newer messages are on the top) and I'm having some problems using the `orderBy` filter that comes with Angular.

Here's an example of what the object we're sorting looks like.

```
$scope.messageThreads = { 
    '102842': {
        name: 'John Doe',
        avatar: 'http://directlink/img.png',
        last_message: 5,
        messages: [ 
            { content: 'Hello!', from: '102842', to: '312124', date: 5 }
        ]
    },
    '59251275': {
        name: 'Thomas Doe',
        avatar: 'http://directlink/img.png',
        last_message: 28,
        messages: [ 
           { content: 'Hey jack', from: '59251275', to: '1231251', date: 12 },
           { content: 'Hey Thomas', from: '1231251', to: '59251275', date: 28 }
        ]
    }
}
```

Stored in a simple object called `messageThreads`.

In the HTML document, we are looping over these in a Key/Value pair, as so:

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, thread) in messageThreads | orderBy: '-thread.last_message'">
    Thread ID: {{id}} - Last message: {{thread.last_message}}
</div>
```

Unfortunately, it's not ordering the messages at all. The output displayed is:

```
Thread ID: 102842 - Last message: 5
Thread ID: 59251275 - Last message: 28
```

However, it should be:

```
Thread ID: 59251275 - Last message: 28
Thread ID: 102842 - Last message: 5
```

Changing `-thread.last_message` to `thread.last_message` does not fix the issue.

Comment: is it possible to paste full code here.

Comment: Basically you can't do this with the data as structured.  From the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat): "You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define the order of keys returned for an object."  And further: "We now rely on the order returned by the browser when running `for key in myObj`. It seems that browsers generally follow the strategy of providing keys in the order in which they were defined...".  "If this is not desired, the recommended workaround is to convert your object into an array..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is solution but one problem with that is it converts the items object to an array, **you will no longer have access to the key** of the “associative array”, as you do with the (key, item) in items snippet

```
   app.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item,key) {
      **item.key = key;** //Here you can push your key to get in returned Object
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

In HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, thread) in messageThreads | orderObjectBy:'last_message':true">
 Thread ID: {{thread.key}} - Last message: {{thread.last_message}}
</div>
```

Comment: How would I go about retaining the key, as the key is essential to functionality in the application. For example, the ng-repeated div also has a `ng-click` on it, which opens a new page based on the key. `ng-click='openThread({{id}})'